# Meteor mongo local access no response

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I do 'meteor mongo' to access my local database (on windows 10) and I try to query it (eg.  db.users.find() ) I get no response.

Comment: with db.users.remove({}) I can remove all the users that I inserted previously

Answer (score 0):

I found that executing the following:

> set MONGO_URL=''

before

> meteor mongo

actually solves the issue.